# ordinalizing dates to show created_at in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to display my date with an ordinal date e.g. 9th Feb 2014. I don't seem to be able to get my syntax right though.  Here's what I have that works, but not sure how to correctly ordinalize the dates. At the moment it says 9 Feb 2014

```
= "Shared #{review.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y")}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shared #{review.created_at.strftime("#{review.created_at.day.ordinalize}" " %b %Y")}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Complete code that words is "Shared #{review.created_at.strftime("#{Time.new.day.ordinalize}" " %b %Y")}"

Comment: @tessad use `review.created_at.day.ordinalize` instead of `Time.new.day.ordinalize`

Comment: `Time.new.day.ordinalize` will always return today's ordinalized date not the review created date

Answer (score 0):

> Time.new.strftime("#{Time.new.day.ordinalize} %b %Y")